# i want to understand why it works this way and not the other way js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this code in my `app.js` file: `router.post('/', stuffCtrl);`
the corresponding code of stuffCtrl is:
this version works fine

```
import Thing from "../models/thing.js"

const createThing = (req, res, next) =>
{
    const thing = new Thing({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
        price: req.body.price,
        userId: req.body.userId
    });
    thing.save().then(() => res.status(201).json({message: "Post saved successfully!"}))
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({error: error})
    );
}

export default createThing;
```

but this version do not work and i absolutely have ni idea why it don't work i want your help to understand why to be able to not reproduce the same error in the futur, thank you very much guys i appreciate.

but if i do it like this:

```
function createThing(req, res, next)
{
    const thing = new Thing({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        imageUrl: req.body.imageUrl,
        price: req.body.price,
        userId: req.body.userId
    });
    thing.save().then(() => res.status(201).json({message: "Post saved successfully!"}))
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({error: error})
    );
}

export default createThing();
```

and change:
`router.post('/', stuffCtrl);`(this code works)
to
`router.post('/', stuffCtrl.createThing);` (this code do not work)

i got this error:

```
file:///Users/curlynux/Documents/go-fullstack-v3-fr/back/controllers/stuff.js:7
        title: req.body.title,
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')
    at createThing (file:///Users/curlynux/Documents/go-fullstack-v3-fr/back/controllers/stuff.js:7:20)
    at file:///Users/curlynux/Documents/go-fullstack-v3-
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Your export statements differ. In the version that does not work you do `export default createThing();` which will call the function createThing without any parameter. That's why `req` is not defined and therefore `req.body` returns an error. Try exporting the function itself without calling it: `export default createThing;`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> export default createThing;
> ```

This exports the `createThing` function.

---

> ```
> export default createThing();
> ```

This calls `createThing` immediately and tries to export its return value.

It doesn't get as far as the export though since it throws an exception because you didn't pass any arguments to it. Hence `req` is undefined.

Comment: how can i use this code `router.post('/', stuffCtrl.createThing);`without break the server ?

Comment: Just don't do the thing I said was the problem